# Como ler arquivo properties para configurar JPA?

Tags: banco-de-dados, java-ee, jpa, persistência

Tenho um arquivo .properties para configurar o banco do meu projeto. Porém não consigo ler o arquivo.

Alguem dá uma força?

**EntityManagerProducer**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

private EntityManagerFactory factory;

public EntityManagerProducer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();

    p.load(new FileInputStream("./conexao.properties"));


    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AlmoxarifadoPU");
}

@Produces @RequestScoped
public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
}

public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
    manager.close();
}
```

**Arquivo properties**

```
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/almoxarifadome"
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: onde esta localizado este arquivo **conexao.properties** ?  em resources? porque não usar o padrão do JPA(persistence.xml) ?

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
InputStream is = null;
Properties p = new Properties();

is = EntityManagerProducer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('conexao.properties');
p.load(is);
```

Fonte:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Não deu certo desse jeito

Comment: Poste o erro que deu.